# How to run selenium python script using chrome browser in ubuntu

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm getting error like that and i have seen below URL and i don't know how to configure with ubuntu(12.04). I know how to configure chrome web driver with windows. Please see below error if any body knows send me a answer.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):      
in setUp driver = webdriver.Chrome() File "/home/pyd/pydan/venvs/local/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", 
line 60, in __init__ self.service.start() File   "/home/pyd/pydan/venvs/local/lib/python2.7/site-   packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.py", 
line 64, in start and read up at   
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver")
```

### WebDriverException: Message: 'ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path.

Answer (score 1):

If you checkout this link, http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver,
there is useful info on where to find the chrome binary on Linux. Also, you might want to check your path environmental variable.

Comment: i have seen above link. but i haven't run chrome webdriver using python webdriver on ubuntu 12.04. do you any ideas for set chrome webdriver in python webdriver . let me know